# How to show files changed on a branch that are modified in the git working tree

Tags: git, branch

I need Linux-only shell pipeline or single script that shows the list
of files that I've locally modified (either staged or unstaged) that
are already committed into some different branch, call that
`topic-branch`, without having to first commit my changes onto any
branch. Typically, `topic-branch`, would be `master`, but not always.
The current git repository may or may not be checked out into
`topic-branch`.

Ideally, the above should be expressed as a *single* git command
whereby I pass it a name of a branch, and it outputs the list in the
format that is emitted by this command:

```
git ls-files --full-name
```

I am not asking for comparing what is already checked into two
separate branches, as there are answers for that already.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answer I have right now, and it works: I add the following
script into a directory that is in my `$PATH`, called `git-cfm`, give
it execute permissions, and then can invoke it via simply:

```
git cfm
```

However, this is not the solution I'm looking for, because it incurs a
social burden to convince my fellow developers to modify their `$PATH`
in their startup scripts (`~/.bashrc` or `~/.cshrc` etc.) to include
the central directory where the `git-cfm` file would resides. Strangely
enough, this is technically possible, but sociologically difficult in
my social context:

```
#!/bin/bash

# git-cfm: <c>hanged <f>iles on <m>aster
#
# List files that have been changed on $branch, that are
# also locally modified (or staged for commit).
# 
# This could be simplified by using, say, Python.
#

# Default $branch to master
branch=${1:-master}

(
  # Get the status using -s which shows both unstaged and staged files
  # in a line-sequential output format, rip off the first column using
  # cut, and then call git-ls-files multiple times on each one to get
  # the full-name of each of them (e.g., a path relative to whatever
  # directory would be returned by "git rev-parse --show-toplevel") .
  # Use the -r option on the call to git-ls-files to avoid calling
  # git-ls-files _unless_ there is actual output from the command,
  # because without the -r, git-ls-files will dump ALL of the files
  # relative to the current working directory, which is NOT what we
  # want.  What we want is the full path name, relative to the
  # top-level directory of the working tree. :
  git status -s 2>/dev/null | cut -c4- | xargs -n100 -r git ls-files --full-name

  # In addition to the above possibly empty output, get all files from
  # all commits on the master branch, that are not changed from
  # commits on the current branch.  Uniquify the output, because of
  # commits that change the same file will result in duplicate files
  # being listed. The empty --pretty option prevents git log default
  # output to include the commit hash, and instead only give us the
  # filenames by using the --name-only option. This comes out as
  # "full-path"'s as indicated above, and is the reason for the
  # --full-name above, too:
  git log --pretty= --name-only @..master | sort | uniq

  # Explanation of the subsequent pipeline below: The file sort and
  # uniq -c emits lines that give counts of occurances in the input.
  # Any occurrances greater than 1 are the ones that we want, so we
  # use awk to show only those. This is just set-theory (AND
  # operation) of the two sets (one set of files per pipeline above)
  # above:
) | sort | uniq -c | awk '{ if ($1 != 1) { print $2; } }'
```